# Logging Jersey using SLF4J in OSGi

Tags: logging, osgi, jersey, slf4j

I am having problems viewing Request/Response information using Jersey within OSGi (Karaf). Apparently Jersey uses JUL logging, so it has to be bridged to SLF4J logging. I do this with the following code:

```
java.util.logging.Logger rootLogger =
java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
java.util.logging.Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
for (int i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
     rootLogger.removeHandler(handlers[i]);
}
org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

Now, to register the Jersey Servlet with OSGi HttpService, I use this:

```
Dictionary<String, String> initParams = new Hashtable<String, String>();
initParams.put("com.sun.ws.rest.config.property.resourceConfigClass", "com.sun.ws.rest.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");
initParams.put("com.sun.ws.rest.config.property.packages","jersey_osgi.rest");

initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters",
"com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter");
initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters",
"com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter");

osgiHttpService.registerServlet("/", servlet, initParams, null);
```

When I hit the servlet, I get the expected response (so everything seems to be up and working), but there are no log entries that tell me what Request/Response was just made. Logging level is set to INFO.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the root logger in a static field. `Logger`s in "java util logging" are usually stored by soft reference so it is possible that your SLF4J configured handler is garbage collected before you use it.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Still not getting any request/response information in the logs.